# Generate own XYZ Tile (MBTiles) - which URL?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web, mbtiles, xyz-tiles

I want to create my own xyz tile for an own basemap on my webspace.
I want to use the own basemap for a qgis2web leaflet map.

This I have done:

1. processing toolbox: generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)
2. I get this file: OUTPUT_FILE.mbtiles
3. created a new XYZ connection
4. the mbtiles file uploaded to 
   https://........../qgis2web/OUTPUT_FILE.mbtiles
   [image]

Question:
**Which URL for the XYZ connection is the right one?**

QGIS 3.10.5 / Windows 10

Comment: A `.mbtiles` is really a `.zip` file containing a hierarchy of tiles inside; see e.g. https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I thought that MBTiles file is a SQLite database and at least GDAL creates such. Are there also other kind of .mbtiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on @IvanSanchez's comment, to get this to work in qgis2web, you'll have to get the contents out of the MBTiles file. Unzip the MBTiles into a directory on your website, retaining the XYZ folder structure. You can then add that location into QGIS as an XYZ layer. qgis2web will then export it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I take the directory export. So I have the folders I need.
My tests are positiv. Is this a disadvantage instead to take the export "generate xyz tiles (mbtiles)"?
I can not unzipped a mbtiles folder.....I do not understand this in this moment.....

Comment: Rename the mbtiles file, changing its file extentsion to .zip. You can then open it, and upload the contents.

Comment: ohh...so easy. Thank you.

Comment: If the answer helped you resolve your problem, it's customary to accept it, not only upvote it, so it's clear that problem was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I have found myself an answer. 
Intead of
"Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)"
i have used
"Generate XYZ tiles (Directory)"

So I can upload this folders to my web account.
And the URL for the xyz tile layer is (example):
https://m y u r l.de/qgis2web/irland/{z}/{x}/{y}.png